# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 menu is repeated 3 times

Tags: menu, ssms

My menu is repeated 3 times. When I click on whatever button the menu is repeated like the second screenshot.

How can I fix it ? Thanks

[image: Screenshot #1]

[image: Screenshot #2]

Comment: did you tried uninstall/reinstall?

Comment: Yes I dit it 2 times...